# how to get the difference of days in dates using 3 textbox

Tags: vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Rlx.png)

```
Public Sub ReturnBooks_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txtoverdue.Text = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, txtdatetoday.Text, txtdatetobereturned.Text).ToString()
End Sub
```

after i load the data from my database and display it to the text boxes.
this is the code i use to get the difference of days in the 2 text box(date to be return and the date today)and display it in the 3rd text box (overdue days).
but i having trouble in DateDiff.

this is the error i get.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30519 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DateDiff' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Function DateDiff(Interval As DateInterval, Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date, [DayOfWeek As FirstDayOfWeek = Sunday], [WeekOfYear As FirstWeekOfYear = Jan1]) As Long': Argument matching parameter 'Date1' narrows from 'String' to 'Date'.
    'Public Function DateDiff(Interval As DateInterval, Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date, [DayOfWeek As FirstDayOfWeek = Sunday], [WeekOfYear As FirstWeekOfYear = Jan1]) As Long': Argument matching parameter 'Date2' narrows from 'String' to 'Date'.
    'Public Function DateDiff(Interval As String, Date1 As Object, Date2 As Object, [DayOfWeek As FirstDayOfWeek = Sunday], [WeekOfYear As FirstWeekOfYear = Jan1]) As Long': Argument matching parameter 'Interval' narrows from 'DateInterval' to 'String'.   Library Management System   C:\Users\Glendon E. Nolo\source\repos\Library Management System\Library Management System\Borrow\ReturnBooks.vb 11  Active

can someone help me to user the right syntax in this.. thank you so much

Comment: What is displayed in the text boxes. I mean the actual text. An example at least.

Comment: You could at least see the problem without running the code if you would turn on Option Strict.  Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: i attached a photo mam .. i updated my post

Comment: All code in a question needs to be formatted as code. Please don't alter my correction.

Comment: Design tip: using DateTimePicker controls in your form would make things easier and require less validation.

Comment: can the time be also shown in datetime picker?

Comment: Yes the DateTimePicker can show time and you can also set a format. An other possible alternative would be a MaskedTextBox control but in the present case the DateTimePicker seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.Text` property is a `String`. A `String` is not a `DateTime`. The `DateDiff` expects a valid `Date` as its second and third parameters. You can check for a valid Data with the `.TryParse` method. You pass in a `String` and a `DateTime` variable to hold the converted Date.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Date1 As DateTime
    Dim Date2 As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, Date1) AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, Date2) Then
        TextBox4.Text = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Date1, Date2).ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```